# SQL Environment change from 2008 to 2017 sql server ( Offset error)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am currently in the process of upgrading my SQL environment from SQL server 2008 to SQL server 2017. I have done this and all is working in my dev environment.

Since moving this to my test environment which has yet to be moved to the newer SQL version I am getting an offset error.

I have seen that this is due to some of my Linq queries having take() and skip() and that this is not available in SQL 2012 and above.

at the moment as I have the two versions is there a work around where the syntax will work for both.

currently I have changed the "providerManifestToken" to 2008 in the EDMX file but wondered if there is a better way?

any help would be great.

Comment: The T-SQL `OFFSET` clause was introduced in SQL 2012 so your database must be in SQL 2012 compatibility level (110) or higher to use in on the server side.

Comment: to do this am I right in thinking I need to amend the compatibility_level in the sys.databases? for the database in question it is currently set to 100?

Comment: The providerManifestToken is a read-only member deep in the EF store model, no chance to hack it at runtime depending on database version. Also, you can't set a database compatibility level to a future level. Only way out: upgrade the test environment.

Comment: When I have updated the providerManifestToken I am no longer getting the error or my test environment (granted that if I need to update model from database in entity it does overwrite.)

Comment: I agree that I am unable to set the compatibility level to a higher level.

Comment: @DanGuzman OFFSET / FETCH requires SQL Server 2012+, but it's not blocked in 100 compatibility level.

Comment: Thanks looks like I will be keeping the providerManifestToken set to 2008 until I have rolled out the release of the later version of SQL across each of my environments.